# If $X$ is a matrix, how can I find the cosine of the angle between a vector of all $1$'s, $\mathbb{1}_n$ and the row space of $X$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $\mathbb{1}_n$ is the $n\times 1$ vector of all $1$'s and that $X$ is a $p \times n$ matrix. Suppose that the projection of the vector $\mathbb{1}_n$ into the row space of $X$ is given by:

$$
U = X^T\left(XX^T\right)^{-1}X \mathbb{1}_n
$$

Then, the angle $\alpha$ is the angle made between the vector $\mathbb{1}_n$ and the row space of $X$. I would like to find $\cos^2(\alpha)$. I know that the answer is supposed to be:

$$
\cos^2(\alpha) = \dfrac{\mathbb{1}_nU}{\mathbb{1}_n^T\mathbb{1}_n}
$$

However, I am not sure how this is derived. I know that in general, for vectors $a$ and $b$,

$$
\cos(\theta) = \frac{a \cdot b}{||a||\cdot ||b||}
$$

However, I cannot get the above if I plug in $\mathbb{1}_n$ and $U$. I cannot get the denominator to look right. Does anyone know what I can do here? Thanks.